# Program hangs with openmpi

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, openmpi, hpc, mpich

I'm running a parallel 
job using **openmpi 2.0.2**, I always get the following Messages in the output file :

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '10.4.12.75' to the list of known hosts.^M
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
No OpenFabrics connection schemes reported that they were able to be
used on a specific port.  As such, the openib BTL (OpenFabrics
support) will be disabled for this port.

  Local host:           hpc488
  Local device:         mlx4_0
  Local port:           2
  CPCs attempted:       rdmacm, udcm
----------------------------------------
```

followed by the **error** message :-

```
[hpc488:45221] 39 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-btl-openib-cpc-base.txt / no cpcs for port
[hpc488:45221] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

The **script** i'm using is as follows:-

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N test
#PBS -q medium
#PBS -l nodes=4:ppn=20
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
export I_MPI_FABRICS shm:dapl
export I_MPI_MPD_TMPDIR /scratch/$USER
mpirun -machinefile $PBS_NODEFILE -np 80 ~/test/cp2k-5.1.0/exe/local/cp2k.popt -i ATP-1.restart >& out
```

The **program also hangs** after some time for eg:-

**Output in the beginning:-**

```
          ----------------------------------- OT ---------------------------------------

  Step     Update method      Time    Convergence         Total energy    

    Change
      ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 OT DIIS     0.80E-01   54.3     0.00002715     -8803.0497995708 -8.80E+03
         2 OT DIIS     0.80E-01   18.8     0.00005469     -8803.0494664995  3.33E-04
         3 OT DIIS     0.80E-01   19.0     0.00001678     -8803.0507564351 -1.29E-03
         4 OT DIIS     0.80E-01   18.9     0.00001380     -8803.0508931318 -1.37E-04
         5 OT DIIS     0.80E-01   19.0     0.00000619     -8803.0510930570 -2.00E-04

      *** SCF run converged in     5 steps ***
```

**Output after some time :-**

```
 ----------------------------------- OT ---------------------------------------

  Step     Update method      Time    Convergence         Total energy    Change
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1 OT DIIS     0.80E-01  543.5     0.00005264     -8803.0309338155 -8.80E+03
     2 OT DIIS     0.80E-01  129.1     0.00017122     -8803.0214844607  9.45E-03
     3 OT DIIS     0.80E-01   97.0     0.00001549     -8803.0324199550 -1.09E-02
     4 OT DIIS     0.80E-01  104.3     0.00001280     -8803.0325293227 -1.09E-04
     5 OT DIIS     0.80E-01  108.0     0.00000682     -8803.0327023147 -1.73E-04

  *** SCF run converged in     5 steps ***
```

Has anyone got any Idea what's going on? I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: In your previous question you asked why your program failed to make progress using MPICH3.2, and told us that it did make progress using OpenMPI 2.0.2.  Now I'm puzzled.  How many questions do you have ?  Does your code execute at all ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark the program runs fine with openmpi 2.0.2 but it hangs after some time as can be seen in the post, and if I run it this way then I will never be able to complete my simulations, this is the reason I shifted to mpich but there I got some other problems, I'm sorry to say, but the management team here for our HPC is pathetic and not at all helpful, that is why I'm seeking for help on online platform's like this. I hope you understand.